# Reuse a hash in YAML

Tags: yaml

I want to [reuse a hash in YAML](http://nodeca.github.com/js-yaml/#yaml=RGVmYXVsdHM6ICZkZWZhdWx0cwogIENvbXBhbnk6IEZvbwogIEl0ZW06IDEyMwoKQ29tcHV0ZXI6ICpkZWZhdWx0cwogIFByaWNlOiAzMDAw):

```
Defaults: &defaults
  Company: Foo
  Item: 123

Computer: *defaults
  Price: 3000
```

However, this generates an error.

Is the only way to anchor each field value separately [like this](http://nodeca.github.com/js-yaml/#yaml=RGVmYXVsdHM6CiAgQ29tcGFueTogJmNvbXBhbnkgRm9vCiAgSXRlbTogJml0ZW0gMTIzCgpDb21wdXRlcjoKICBDb21wYW55OiAqY29tcGFueQogIEl0ZW06ICppdGVtCiAgUHJpY2U6IDMwMDA=)?

```
Defaults:
  Company: &company Foo
  Item: &item 123

Computer:
  Company: *company
  Item: *item
  Price: 3000
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
# sequencer protocols for Laser eye surgery
---
- step:  &id001                  # defines anchor label &id001
    instrument:      Lasik 2000
    pulseEnergy:     5.4
    pulseDuration:   12
    repetition:      1000
    spotSize:        1mm

- step: &id002
    instrument:      Lasik 2000
    pulseEnergy:     5.0
    pulseDuration:   10
    repetition:      500
    spotSize:        2mm

- step: *id001                   # refers to the first step (with anchor &id001)
- step: *id002                   # refers to the second step
- step: *id001
- step: *id002
```

sample from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components)

Comment: The answer by Gabriel is a better way to solve this problem. You can reuse a whole group, then override the fields (even deep fields) that you want to be different.

Answer (score 362):

Try reusing a full group by importing it:

```
Defaults: &defaults
  Company: foo
  Item: 123

Computer:
  <<: *defaults
  Price: 3000
```

Documentation: http://yaml.org/type/merge.html

Comment: I always forget this syntax, it's kind of complicated.

Comment: Is there documentation you can link to for this? I'd like to see if there is a similar feature for lists.

Comment: For a DSL that is supposedly easy to read and understand, this syntax is notoriously complicated and unreadable.


Then you'd think reading the docs/specs would clear it out, but no, you'd end up with a deep hole in your head from all the intense scratching while trying to decipher the specification.

Comment: I'd go as far as to argue this would be a place were code duplication is better - and I hate duplication in general.

Comment: This answer shows exactly how it works. And using two characters is *not* complicated! An `&` with a name to mark a section  and a `*` with the same name to recall it. That's very simple. You mark a line with `&name`, and everything nested below that line is then reused with `*name`. Thanks for this post, it's quite helpful, despite these comments saying it's complicated...

Comment: It seems there's only one instance of data shared between different parts. If you modify anywhere. All parts refering this instance will be affected. Is it possible to create seperate instances for each referring part?