# Using Similar "suites" in Test Kitchen for Code Reuse?

Tags: yaml, chef-infra

How can I re-use all of my `attributes` section, except for `maven`

```
     suites:
       - name: DEV

     attributes: 
          'ant': &ant
            'version': '1.9.3'
            'home': '/my/path/ant'
          'maven':  
            'version': 3
            'm2_home': '/my/path/maven'
            '3': 
              'version': '3.2.1'
              'maven_rc': 
            'opts': ''
```

For my `TESTING` instance, I would like to inherit all of the above attributes, except for `maven`, which I'd like to override (different version):

```
    - name: TESTING

     attributes:  
          <<: *ant        # re-use ant as it's the same configuration
          'maven':        # different version for TESTING
            'version': 3
            'm2_home': '/my/path/maven'
            '3': 
              'version': '3.0.5'
              'maven_rc': 
            'opts': ''
```

Comment: You want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466223/reuse-a-block-of-code-in-yaml

Comment: Thanks, Seth. I read that article and updated my question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: How about creating a `base` or `default` run_list, that you then inherit from in both `dev` and `qa`, with qa adding a recipe on top? Note that you would have to inherit only `run_list`, not the entire suite.

Comment: @JeanMertz - could you please post an answer? (1) for credit (2) I'm not sure how to use inheritance in YAML

Comment: @KevinMeredith turns out I was incorrect, it seems in YAML you *can't* inherit and then append any extra values in the same namespace, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to edit your `.kitchen.yml` under the platform for any attributes you want to be universal.  If you would like to change them then you just put them under the suites section with a different value.

```
platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
    driver_config:
      box: ubuntu-12.04
    run_list:
      - recipe[apt::default]
    attributes:
      ant: &ant
        version: '1.9.3'
        home: '/my/path/ant'
      maven:
        version: 3
        m2_home: '/my/path/maven'
        3:
          version: '3.2.1'
          maven_rc:
        opts: ''

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[cookbook::default]
    attributes:

  - name: testing
    run_list:
      - recipe[cookbook::default]
    attributes:
      maven:
        3:
          version: '3.0.5'
```

You can then access the attributes inside the recipes by calling `node['maven']['version']` to retrieve the current value which will change depending if it is overwritten in the suites section.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that you can use Erb syntax in your kitchen.yml

`<% my_attrs = {'foo' => 'bar'} %>
suites:
- name: one
  attributes:
    <%= my_attrs.to_yaml %>
- name: two
  attributes:
    <%= my_attrs.merge('baz' => 'whatever').to_yaml %>`

Overusing this can quickly lead to unreadable configs, but in moderation it can be useful.