# String constant for use in en.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my locales/en.yml, I have the following:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      ticket:
        customer_name: "Customer Name"
      inventory:
        quantity: 'Quantity'
      resources:
        quantity: 'Quantity'
      hours:
        quantity: 'Quantity'
```

Is there a way for me to define the string 'Quantity' as a string constant so I can re-use the constant in my en.yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: username
  password: YOURDBPASSWORD

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
```

Also see answer: [Reuse a block of code in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466223/reuse-a-block-of-code-in-yaml?answertab=active#tab-top)