# Intake: catalogue level parameters

Tags: python, intake

I am reading about "parameters" [here](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/catalog.html#parameter-definition) and wondering whether I can define catalogue level parameters that I can later use in the definition of the catalogue's sources?

Consider a simple YAML-catalogue with two sources:

```
sources:
  data1:
    args:
      urlpath: "{{CATALOG_DIR}}/data/{{snapshot_date}}/data1.csv"
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.csv.CSVSource
    metadata: {}
    
  data2:
    args:
      urlpath: "{{CATALOG_DIR}}/data/{{snapshot_date}}/data2.csv"
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.csv.CSVSource
    metadata: {}
```

Note that both data sources (data1 and data2) make use of `snapshot_date` parameter inside `urlpath` argument? With this definition I can load data sources with:

```
cat = intake.open_catalog("./catalog.yaml")
cat.data1(snapshot_date="latest").read()   # reads from data/latest/data1.csv
cat.data2(snapshot_date="20211029").read() # reads from data/20211029/data2.csv
```

Please note that `cat.data1().read()` will not work, since `snapshot_date` defaults to empty string, so the csv driver cannot find the path "./data//data1.csv".

I can set the default value by adding `parameters` section to every (!) source like in the below.

```
sources:
  data1:
    parameters:
      snapshot_date:
        type: str
        default: "latest"
        description: ""
    args:
      urlpath: "{{CATALOG_DIR}}/data/{{snapshot_date}}/data1.csv"
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.csv.CSVSource
    metadata: {}
    
  data2:
    parameters:
      snapshot_date:
        type: str
        default: "latest"
        description: ""
    args:
      urlpath: "{{CATALOG_DIR}}/data/{{snapshot_date}}/data2.csv"
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.csv.CSVSource
    metadata: {}
```

But this looks complicated (too much repetitive code) and a little inconvenient for the end user -- if a user wants to load all data sources from a given date, he has to explicitly provide `snapshot_date` parameter to every(!) data source at initialization. IMO, it would be nice I user can provide this value once when initializing the catalog.

Is there a way I can define `snapshot_date` parameter at catalog level? So that:

- I can set default value (e.g. "latest" in my example) in the YAML-definition of the catalogue's parameter
- or can pass catalogue's parameter value at runtimeduring the call `intake.open_catalog("./catalog.yaml", snapshot_date="20211029")`
- this value should be accessible in the definition of data sources of this catalog
  ?

```
cat = intake.open_catalog("./catalog.yaml", snapshot_date="20211029")
cat.data1.read()  # will return data from ./data/20211029/data1.csv
cat.data2.read()  # will return data from ./data/20211029/data2.csv
cat.data2(snapshot_date="latest").read()  # will return data from ./data/latest/data1.csv

cat = intake.open_catalog("./catalog.yaml")
cat.data1.read()  # will return data from ./data/latest/data1.csv
cat.data2.read()  # will return data from ./data/latest/data2.csv
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea has been suggested before ( https://github.com/intake/intake/pull/562 , https://github.com/intake/intake/issues/511 ), and I have an inkling that maybe https://github.com/zillow/intake-nested-yaml-catalog supports something like you are asking.

However, I fully support adding this functionality in Intake, either based on #562, above, or otherwise. Adding it to the base Catalog and YAML file(s) catalog should be easy, but doing it so that it works for all subclasses might be tricky.

Currently, you can achieve what you want using environment variables, e.g., "{{snapshot_date}}"->"{{env(SNAPSHOT_DATE)}}", but you would ned to communicate to the user that this variable should be set. In addition, if the value is not to be used within a string, you would still need a parameter definition to cast to the right type.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant!
I like the motivation with DB connection settings parameters in the #562. This is something I faced too when started using [intake-sql](https://github.com/intake/intake-sql). I do not want to put sqlalchemy connection string into the catalog YAML file, so I have to pass within python code every time I initialize a data source. It would be more convenient to pass this as a parameter to catalog once and then sources can just use it. Would love to see this functionality added to intake.

Comment: Consider it on the todo list

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but consider a `yaml` file with this content:

```yaml
global_params:
  snapshot_date: &global
    default: latest
    description: ''
    type: str

sources:
  data1:
    args:
      urlpath: '{{CATALOG_DIR}}/data/{{snapshot_date}}/data1.csv'
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.csv.CSVSource
    metadata: {}
    parameters:
      snapshot_date: *global
  data2:
    args:
      urlpath: '{{CATALOG_DIR}}/data/{{snapshot_date}}/data2.csv'
    description: ''
    driver: intake.source.csv.CSVSource
    metadata: {}
    parameters:
      snapshot_date: *global
```

Now `intake` will accept keyword argument for `snapshot_date` for specific sources.

Some relevant answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651436/10693596) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197237/10693596).